# Query string showing after javascript redirect

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, .htaccess

I've been using .htaccess to eliminate my query strings and display my url in a nice neat way.  This has been working great until this point in time.  I can visit a page such as www.example.com/speakers/ (which will actually be www.example.com/speakers.php) which works, as expected.  Same with other pages or other pages stored in the database.  HOWEVER, on the "speakers" page I have a select option to select the year to view the speakers (just your standard select element).  I select "2018" to view the speakers for 2018 and it redirects to `www.example.com/speakers/2018/?ax=2018&do=&third=`

Why is it showing the query string when it redirects.  I have used this .htaccess process on many pages before with redirects exactly like this and it doesn't show the query string (same web host and everything).

**.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
     RewriteEngine On
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^/]*)
     RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1.php -f
     RewriteRule ^([^/]*)(/([^/]*))?(/([^/]*))?(/([^/]*))? /$1.php?ax=$3&do=$5&third=$7 [L]
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
     RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]*)/(.*)$ /content.php?url=$1/$2 [L]
     Options +FollowSymLinks
     RewriteEngine on
 </IfModule>
 <IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
     ErrorDocument 404 /content.php?err=404
 </IfModule>
```

** Code & Inline Javascript **

```
 <form>
      <select name="year" id="year" style="padding: 5px; font-size: 14px;">
          <option value='0'>-- Choose a Year --</option>
          <option value="2018">2018</option>
      </select>
 </form>
 <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
           $("#year").on('change',function() {
                if($(this).val()!=0) {
                     window.location = '/speakers/'+$(this).val();
                }
           });
      });
 </script>
```

Comment: Enable rewrite logging and find out …?

Comment: It is a shared server ran by my hosting company so I don't think I can.

Comment: I can’t see why/how this would issue an _external_ redirect, there is nothing in the .htaccess that should result in one as far as I can see. But maybe there’s more rewriting going on at an upper level (done by the provider) that interferes somehow.

Comment: I don't know either, I'll ask my hosting company if I can enable rewrite logging or how to do it if I can but I won't get a response until in the morning. :\

Comment: This appears to be the only thing I can find in my RAW Logs pertaining to the redirect.
`- - [06/Sep/2018:10:34:50 -0600] "GET /speakers/2018/?ax=2018&do=&third= HTTP/1.1" 200 16170 "https://www.example.ca/speakers/2018/speakers/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0"
- - [06/Sep/2018:10:34:50 -0600] "GET /speakers/2018 HTTP/1.1" 200 16170 "https://www.example.ca/speakers/2018/speakers/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0"`

Comment: So the request for `/speakers/2018/?ax=2018&do=&third=` seems to have the referrer `https://www.example.ca/speakers/2018/speakers/` set - but wait, why is that `/speakers/2018/speakers/` in the first place, should that not just be `/speakers/2018/`? Sure you are creating the correct URL on the client side with your dropdown selection?

Comment: Everything that pertains to redirecting on the client side is shown above.  You can view the actual page at http://www.agupdate.ca/speakers/

Comment: That just goes to https://www.agupdate.ca/speakers/2018 for me when I select the year, and _stays_ on that URL. Are you sure you’ve not been fooled by your browser cache here? ;-)

Comment: Well, I don't understand the logs with the `/speakers/2018/speakers/` bit; however clearing my cache does resolve the query string issue. <:-)  I figured that since before it was /speakers.php?ax=2018 that the browser would recognize /speakers/2018/ as a different page. haha